# Android Buttons in ScrollView sized to half the screen

Tags: android, button

I want to be able to scroll through buttons in a scrollview, and have each button be half the size of the screen.

```
_____________
/__________\
| BUTTON 1 |
\__________/

/__________\
| BUTTON 2 |
\__________/
_____________
```

...scroll a bit...

```
_____________
| BUTTON 1 |
\__________/

/__________\
| BUTTON 2 |
\__________/
_____________
```

... bit more...

```
_____________
\__________/

/__________\
| BUTTON 2 |
\__________/

/__________\
| BUTTON 3 |
_____________
```

If it was just in a LinearLayout, I'd use layout_weight set to 1, but I don't think that would work in a ScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought, you'd almost definitely have to do this programatically with screen measurements. I just switched to using a ViewFlipper and previous/next buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct. 
ScrollView must have one direct child beneath it.
So add the scrollview as the parent layout and a linear layout inside it and do whatever you want.

UPDATE:
Now I get what you mean. Then you should get the screen width and height, do some mathematics and adjust the height and width attribute of your buttons to the desired ones.

Maybe extend the button class in order to just implement it one time and then include it in your layout xml as a custom view. The way I see it there isn't some layout parameters you could pass in order to adjust the buttons' size.

Comment: That won't work because the layout_weight won't work as I want. Think about it, the layout_weight simply insures the buttons are sized the same.

Comment: I get what you mean, sure you don't just want to measure the Scrollview and set the height programmatically then?